# Scrolling to a dynamically highlighted table row

Tags: javascript, scroll

When you arrive at the current month's page, javascript in the source code highlights the row that represents today.  How can I get the page to scroll down to that row automatically?  Page is http://www.itsmyturnnow.com/HWC/BRP/08.htm and script I was given is in source code.  Thanks.

```
var INTENDED_MONTH = 7 //August
// INTENDED_MONTH is zero-relative
now = new Date().getDate(),
rows = document.getElementById('scripture').rows;
if (new Date().getMonth() != INTENDED_MONTH) {
    // need a value here less than 1, or the box for the first of the month will be in Gold
    now = 0.5
};
for (var i = 0, rl = rows.length; i < rl; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].childNodes;
    for (j = 0, cl = cells.length; j < cl; j++) {
        if (cells[j].nodeName == 'TD'
  && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue != ''
  && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue == now) {
            rows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red' // 'ffff99' // '#ffd700' // TODAY - gold
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery in the function which hilights the current psalm:

```
var INTENDED_MONTH = 7 //August
// INTENDED_MONTH is zero-relative
now = new Date().getDate(),
rows = document.getElementById('scripture').rows;
if (new Date().getMonth() != INTENDED_MONTH) {
    // need a value here less than 1, or the box for the first of the month will be in Gold
    now = 0.5
};
for (var i = 0, rl = rows.length; i < rl; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].childNodes;
    for (j = 0, cl = cells.length; j < cl; j++) {
        if (cells[j].nodeName == 'TD'
  && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue != ''
  && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue == now) {
            rows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red' // 'ffff99' // '#ffd700' // TODAY - gold
            $('html,body').delay(1000).animate({scrollTop:rows[i].offsetTop}, 500);

        }

    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QT3v5/22/
​

Comment: Each page is already the current month.  What I need the script to do is automatically scroll down to the row that my script highlighted as the current day.

Comment: Also, there is no way to include an id #currentday as the highlighting of the day row happens dynamically.

Comment: I see, I messed up the terms a bit. Edited my answer according to your needs.

Comment: Ok, I will try to be more clear.  Please look at the javascript in my source code at the end of the html.  The javascript already dynamically highlights (changes the style color of) the row that is today's scripture reading.  But when you go to the August page, the highlighted row is not visible.  I cannot name the row because the correct row to highlight is determined on the fly by the script.  And I don't want a button to execute it, I need it to happen with the script that changes the color of the row.  so change color and then move (scroll) to row in browser.  Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense, yeah. Is it possible to add the piece of the script that hilights the row to your question?

Comment: It won't let me paste that many characters...  How can I paste a script snippet like you did?  Also, it's in the source at the url I entered earlier.

Comment: var INTENDED_MONTH = 7 //August
    // INTENDED_MONTH is zero-relative
    now = new Date().getDate(),
    rows = document.getElementById('scripture').rows;
    if (new Date().getMonth() != INTENDED_MONTH) {
        // need a value here less than 1, or the box for the first of the month will be in Gold
        now = 0.5
    };

    for (var i = 0, rl = rows.length; i < rl; i++) {
        var cells = rows[i].childNodes;
        for (j = 0, cl = cells.length; j < cl; j++) {

Comment: if (cells[j].nodeName == 'TD'
      && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue != ''
      && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue == now) {
                rows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red' // 'ffff99' // '#ffd700' // TODAY - gold
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @TedLederer: You should add it to your original question, not to the comments here :P

Comment: @TedLederer: Then this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/QT3v5/1/ I added `rows[i].scrollIntoView();` after `rows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'` Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks a million!!  Now, is there a way to get that last part to be delayed for about 1 or 2 seconds... just so that a user can see that they are in the right month, and then it smoothly scrolls into view?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, but that would require JQuery scrolling to a certain element after the document has loaded.

Comment: What about using a settimeout() before the "rows[i].scrollIntoView();" fires?

Comment: That was what I was thinking, but that won't guarantee a smooth scroll effect. I'll have to try something using JQuery.

Comment: @TedLederer: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/QT3v5/22/ I changed the `rows[i].scrollIntoView();` to the JQuery ` $('html,body').delay(1000).animate({scrollTop:rows[i].offsetTop}, 500);`. Change the delay value according to your needs (it's in milliseconds).

Comment: Thanks Silox!  Have a look at the url and see how it works!  Very nice transition! I appreciate your help!!

Comment: I have added rows[i].style.color = 'white' to make the font color white where the row gets highlighted.  But because some of the text is dynamically set to be a hyperlink, the regular text goes white, but the text with the link stays black.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not need jQuery. It applies an ID to the current row, the calculates the position of the row in pixels, and then scrolls to that position.

```
var INTENDED_MONTH = 7 //August
// INTENDED_MONTH is zero-relative
now = new Date().getDate(),
rows = document.getElementById('scripture').rows;
if (new Date().getMonth() != INTENDED_MONTH) {
    // need a value here less than 1, or the box for the first of the month will be in Gold
    now = 0.5
};
for (var i = 0, rl = rows.length; i < rl; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].childNodes;
    for (j = 0, cl = cells.length; j < cl; j++) {
        if (cells[j].nodeName == 'TD'
  && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue != ''
  && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue == now) {
            rows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red' // 'ffff99' // '#ffd700' // TODAY - gold
            rows[i].setAttribute('id', 'currentRow');
            function findPos(obj) {
                var curtop = 0;
                if (obj.offsetParent) {
                    do {
                        curtop += obj.offsetTop;
                    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
                return [curtop];
                }
            }
            window.scroll(0,findPos(document.getElementById('currentRow')));
        }
    }
}
```

It's currently working for me.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54mhv/)

Comment: But this is not a smooth scroll what @TedLederer was asking for in the comments to my solution.